# Is it possible to make scrollwheel up perform a PressKey event, and NOT scroll wheel up, within LUA script?

Tags: logitech-gaming-software

As the title suggests, I want to make it so that scrollwheel up performs a PressKey event, but it is important that it does not perform a scrollwheel up event. In other words, I want to rebind the key. Normally I would just do this in the LGS interface, but I only want this to happen under certain circumstances, namely, while I am holding Right Mouse Button. Is this possible?

Comment: `Normally I would just do this in the LGS interface` - Please show how can you rebind wheel up/down to something else in LGS interface.  AFAIK only wheel click is bindable in LGS, not wheel rotate.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/Acryhx3)

Here is a picture of the part of my LGS where I can bind it

Comment: Thanks for the picture.  But this is scroll left/right and wheel click.  How can you bind to wheel up/down?

Comment: That's... a really good point. I just assumed it meant up and down, but sure enough I can actually push my scroll wheel sideways. I had no idea! Nevertheless, I would still like to bind this via scripting. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't have a mouse with horizontal scroll, so please test what `event` and `arg` are generated for wheel scroll left/right?